# How to pass a fresh _id from a method insert into a subscription/publication?

Tags: meteor, iron-router

I have an app where you can choose (or add if they don't exist!) a superhero/villain `character` from a certain `universe` on the **first** page; then outfit him with weapons, clothes, and gadgets on the **second** page (`build`).

I have this route defined:

```
Router.route('/build/:character', {
  name: 'build'
  waitOn: Meteor.subscribe('characters', {name: this.params.character})
  //and a few other subscriptions and sessions as well for the items
  //and stuff, but those don't matter here.
}
```

The link from the specific character, though, passes along a query as well:

```
 <a href="{{pathFor 'build' query=this.universe}}">
```

So the final link could look something like this:

```
/build/Aquaman?DCComics
```

Now the page you are on will display a list of weapons and gadgets where you could also add other stuff if you so wish. Then you are supposed to drag the items you want to include onto your version of this hero.

Problem is, at this point the app doesn't know you even want to create your own hero. Maybe the user is just looking through them for fun. **There's a button that the user has to click first to initialize the creating process, and that's when the actual `_id` is created**, something like this:

```
Meteor.methods({
  buildHero: function(heroCharacterName, heroUniverse) {
    var heroToAdd = {}
    heroToAdd['characterName'] = heroCharacterName
    heroToAdd['universe'] = heroUniverse
    heroToAdd['_createdAt'] = new Date()
    CreatedHeroes.insert(heroToAdd, function() {
      if (! error)
        //Update the subscription somehow...
    })
  }
})
```

So, the `_id` that is created here in the new Collection must be passed along to a subscription somehow, because I don't want the user to see other personal heroes that have been created, only his own newly created one.

The solution I have in mind is adding the `_id` onto the URL in form of a hastag, and use `this.params.hash` in the subscription like so:

```
Router.route('/build/:character', {
   name: 'build'
   waitOn: [Meteor.subscribe('characters', {name: this.params.character}),
     Meteor.subscribe('createdheroes', this.params.hash)]
}
```

First of all, is this a valid approach? If so, how do I accomplish it; how do I actually update the URL to include this hash?

If not, what would be a better approach?

Comment: You use the word "refresh", but I'm unclear what exactly you are solving for. A common way to deal with this kind of problem is to change the route/url to one using the id returned by the method. For example on url `/x` we get a new id and route to `/x/:id`. Is there some reason you can't call `Router.go` in the method's callback?

Comment: No reason except I don't want to refresh the page with a redirect or render.

Comment: @DavidWeldon Updated my question so it shouldn't be unclear anymore what I'm trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to handle this logic in the data context or in a template helper and not in the way of subscribing/publishing.

If I was you I would besure that the newly created item is being published and subscribed by the client and modify your search query just that it only adds the newly created item.

Comment: Just be sure you subscribed to the last items return Items.find(). When this is an overkill you can limit the result but be sure you always got the last items

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if I understand your question well but what I got, you will know the last _id which was used on your insert.

Instead of letting done this automatically by meteor, just use the meteor method to create / get that _id value >> [see Meteor Documentation](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/mongo_object_id)

```
var new_id = new Mongo.ObjectID()
col1.insert({ _id: new_id, ... });
col2.insert({ ..., ref_col1_id: new_id, ... });
```

Comment: I don't see how this is different from just getting the `_id` the normal way?

Comment: ??? what do you mean with "the normal way"? When I read your question you want to know the `_id` value from the next document insertion to use it later on. Instead trying to receive this new `_id` AFTER insert, you can create it BEFORE and therefor use it also in your client. You may set e.g. Session.set('next_id', _id); BEFORE insert and wait for at router or whatever. You also may use col.observe to listen for action on the incoming infos to that `_id`. Isn't what your asking for?

Comment: No I can't create it before since it's dependent on user action.

Comment: As I said, I did not understand your request quite well and also not your usecase. But isn't it: User Action -> (creade _id, session.set(_id), use _id) -> Somewhere else: Wait for _id

Comment: No session involved. Click a button to create a new object into which the user can drag items from the frame above to store them.

Comment: ??? Session (vars) are always avaible at meteor client app or use template based ReactiveVars. I am not sure what you are looking for and how familar you are with Meteor but "Click a button to create a new object into which the user can drag items from the frame above to store them" could be solved as I said. Just store the key to somewhere Reactive or Session var and use it on drag events.

Comment: Why do you need to reload the page? Just create 2 tempates and a helper which one should be visible. Then you can switch between list and action view without page reload. Maybe you use also some css framework like ionic as well and get ui elements like sliding panes for better user experiences.

Comment: I DONT need to reload the page. I dont want the sessions to be cleared WHEN/IF the user refreshes the page. In fact, I don't want to use sessions at all. They are out of the question.